# A puzzle between child and parent process over pipe

Tags: c

Currently I'm leaning how to use pipe between child process and parent process, simply parent process writes to a pipe and child would read from pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define READEND 0
#define WRITEEND 1
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  if (fork()){
     close(fd[READEND]);
     int write_number;
     for (int i = 2; i < 36; i++){
         write_number = i;
         write(fd[WRITEEND], &write_number, sizeof(write_number));
     }
     close(fd[WRITEEND]);
     wait(0);
  }else{// child process
     close(fd[WRITEEND]);
     int read_number[34];
     int len;
     int prime;
     int read_pipe = fd[READEND];
     while ((len = read(read_pipe, &read_number, sizeof(read_number))) > 0){
         printf("len : %d, %d\n", len / 4, getpid());
     }
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

When I run multiple times, something quite unusual happened, but I have no idea, here is the output:

```
~# ./a.out
len : 34, 30375
~# ./a.out
len : 34, 30383
~# ./a.out
len : 1, 30397
len : 1, 30397
len : 1, 30397
len : 31, 30397
~# ./a.out
len : 34, 30411
~# cc pipe_pipe.c
~# ./a.out
len : 33, 30454
len : 1, 30454
```

It seems like the child goes to the next iteration in the while loop, so that's why not only one line output, but I have closed all the write end of the pipe, it should know that I will just read once, but some runs do not output 34...
So can anyone analyze that why it is this? thx

Comment: Classical race condition. Still, in all cases, 34 elements were written and 34 elements were received, even though they were not received in one piece.

Comment: "it should know that I will just read once".  Why?  If you rewrite the parent so that it only writes once you will get some atomicity guarantees, but the parent is making multiple writes.  It can be swapped out at any time and the writes will be interleaved with times that the child is running.

Comment: What is `printf("len : %d, %d\n", len / 4, getpid());`? Probably you meant to write `printf("len : %d, %d\n", len / sizeof *read_number, getpid());`, but it's hard to be sure because magic numbers are confusing.

Comment: In the read system call ,if read return it will read specific number of bytes or less, there is no guarantee of that, but at the end it will absolute receive 0, case write end is closed both in child and parent, so ideally it will receive 34 elements, but no guarantee...thx

Comment: @William Pursell, my bad coding style, thx for mention it, I will change that later

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes running in parallel.  When you call `read`, there is no guarantee that all the writes have been executed by the other process, so the `read` call will not be able to return all 34 integers and will probably just return whatever is in the pipe.

With a little more work, you can probably put the read end of the pipe into blocking mode, meaning that it will try to wait until all the data you requested has been read before it returns.

Comment: yeah, I tried that, which is also reliable, thx!